# Which Groovy (or Java) type to pass which supports "inputStream"?

Tags: grails

I have a method like this.

```
def process(file){
  if(file != null && !file.empty){
   anotherMethod(file.inputStream);
  }
}
```

If I call this method from Java, what type of object do I need to pass into this method? I tried File,ZipFile but they don't have empty method.

Comment: Could you add any explanation to this question? I don't know about such an object.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to say for definite without seeing more context (where is this method usually called from the Grails application, for example), but a possible candidate would be [MultipartFile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html), or rather one of its concrete implementations such as [MockMultipartFile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockMultipartFile.html). The `empty` and `inputStream` properties that the groovy code is accessing correspond to the `isEmpty()` and `getInputStream()` bean-style accessor methods of this interface.

The normal purpose of this type is to handle `multipart/form-data` file uploads - it's what you get when you call `request.getFile('fieldName')` in a controller.